# Team member deleted "Release" configuration. How would I recreate it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I had a team member delete the release configuration from one of our projects. While I do have the removal in source control, there were many changes to the solution in the offending commit. I figured it would be easier to recreate the profile rather than reverting (as this was done months ago).

I recreated a profile called "Release" through the Configuration Manager. Upon building the solution however, I've discovered the project binaries are still in debug mode (using this [tool](http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/)).

At this point I have gone through the solution file in a text editor and tried to compare it to the last known working version. Here is the entry for my new release config:

{9191D2A0-00A9-4A1C-9EAC-8837577D473F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
   {9191D2A0-00A9-4A1C-9EAC-8837577D473F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
   {9191D2A0-00A9-4A1C-9EAC-8837577D473F}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
  {9191D2A0-00A9-4A1C-9EAC-8837577D473F}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
  {9191D2A0-00A9-4A1C-9EAC-8837577D473F}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
  {9191D2A0-00A9-4A1C-9EAC-8837577D473F}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU

Does anyone know what settings I need to tweak to get this new build configuration to actually build in release mode, or I am stuck in merge hell trying to revert the commit?

EDIT:

Here is my configuration after I created a new release profile:
[image]

However after compiling with these settings, the dlls are debug. 
[image]

Comment: How are the builds being triggered? This is the correct configuration.

Comment: after making sure the solution is set to use the new release configuration, I press ctrl-shift-B to build the solution.

Comment: Just to make sure.... in the toolbar of your VS you do have "release" and 'Any CPU' selected? Also try using the menu build command when you have your top level (UI) project selected, when I tried your build shortcut my solution built projects that are not part of the main project so I'm not 100% sure what that shortcut is doing actually. The normal build shortcut is just shift+F6

Comment: This was in VS 2015 community edition. They replaced shift+F6 with that wonky shortcut for that version :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to go through each project in the solution and individually check the build settings for that project.  You can do this by right-clicking the project in the solution explorer and selecting properties.  Navigate to the Build tab:

[image: Project Build Properties]

Verify that the correct configuration is selected from the combo boxes at the top and then check the appropriate boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to top menu->Build->Configuration Manager
In there set the project configurations to release when you have the Active solution configuration set to release. Save the solution.

The solution configuration (in the sln file) is really just a name for a collection of flags for the solutions projects, the configurations defined in the configuration manager for the PROJECTS in reference to the named solution configuration are what msbuild is actually using during the build process.

Comment: There is no release in Active Solution Configuration. Thats the problem. I created a "release," but it doesn't actually compile as such

Comment: If it is not in the list then simply select "<new>" and create one called 'release' and continue as I stated. What you have in your original post IS that represented in the sln file, if you made those changes to the file did you actually save the sln? If you did you should see a release config in the configuration manager.

Comment: I did create one called release. the sln is saved. it just doesn't compile as released. I'll update my question with screen shots

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Studio 2022

Add a new project to the solution and rebuild. The `Release` configuration will be available in both the `Solution Configuration` dropdown and **Configuration Manager**

### Just in Case

**Adding a Project to a Solution**

1. Open the **Solution Explorer** `CTRL + ALT + L`
2. Right-Click the Solution
3. Hover over **Add** then click **New Project...**
4. Choose `Console App` (or what ever you want)
5. Click **Next**
6. Click **Next**
7. Click **Create**

When your done, remove the project from the solution